# Fancybox and Transparency

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, lightbox

Will do my best to explain this. =>

I am using Fancybox and everything works great. Here comes the issue. I have an image that is semi-transparent. When the image is loaded instead of seeing part of the background where the image is there is a background color. Is there a way to have the background (behind the image) be transparent? I am not referring to the overlay. I am referring to directly behind the image.

Thanks for any and all help and advice.

Here is the code for the Fancybox:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
   var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function(){

        Engine.Initialize(); //This line is for other JS - not fancybox

    $j("#start").fancybox({
     'padding' : 0
    });
  });
</script>
```

[Here is the screenshot showing what I am referring to.](http://screencast.com/t/EwrmWl7kfdb)

***EDIT***
Updated code for a couple changes I made with page since post and added screenshot of issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
$j("a.fancybox").fancybox({
    onComplete: function() {
        $('#fancybox-outer').css('opacity', '0.4');
    }
});
```

...or...

```
#fancybox-outer {
    opacity: .4 !important;
}
```

Comment: That made the whole image transparent not the background. I added a screenshot and updated code (I made a couple changes with the page since the post)

Comment: @UBhapE2 Opacity in CSS is inherited. The easiest method would be to change the background of `#fancybox-outer` to a semi transparent PNG.

Comment: That is it! Here was the final code that works great! : #fancybox-outer { background:transparent url('../images/skin/fancybox-transparent.png') repeat 0px 0px !important; 
  }